# C++: Constructing std::function from templated method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std, std-function

So, I was trying to get this working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class X {
    public:
    template<typename T>
    void f(T t) {
        cout << t << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    X xx;
    xx.f(5);
    function<void(int)> ff(&X::f);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler complains that `X::f` is `<unresolved overloaded function type>`, which makes sense. Now, my questions is: how do I tell the compiler which template parameters to use? I essentially want something like

```
&X::template<int> f
```

(the equivalent of dot-template for object methods). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need:

```
function<void(X, int)> ff(&X::f<int>)
ff(xx, 5);
```

because you asked for a non-static member function meaning you need to provide the instance on which the function is invoked to `std::function`. For example: http://ideone.com/dYadxQ

If your member `f` doesn't actually need an `X` to operate, you should make it a "free" nonmember function rather than a member function of `X`.

Comment: One can use `std::bind` or lambda to fit the signature `function <void(int)>`.